# What is the difference between sqlalchemy.ext.serializer and pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, sqlalchemy, pickle

I am trying to dump serialized SQLAlchemy ORM objects to a file.  To be more specific an object I need to dump is mapped to a row of database table.

I found that this task can be done with either the pickle module or by using sqlalchemy.ext.serializer.

The generated file sizes for these two approaches differ where the pickle module generates the larger file. The problem I have is which approach is the better one and what are the reasons for the underlying differences of the two.